# How To Check Whether Someone Is Actively Using Their Computer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that posts to a database every minute, to show that is running.  This is good to make sure that the program is running on a person's computer, but it doesn't tell whether the person is actually actively using their computer (the computer can be locked, or the person might be out of the office, with the program still running and posting to the database).

What is the best way to check if the person is actually actively using the computer?

The first idea that pops into my mind is to create a MessageBox that opens every 5 minutes asking the user to press "OK" if they are present.  This would provide the needed functionality, but would annoy the daylights out of anyone using it.

Is there any more behind-the-scenes way to detect whether a person is using their computer?  Maybe checking for whether it is locked, or can a WinForm application tell when the mouse and keyboard is being used, even when the WinForm is not the active window?

Any suggestions or help in this matter would be appreciated, thanks!

Addendum: I will assume that if the mouse and keyboard are not being used, a person is not using that particular box (so this would cause a false positive if the user is watching a movie on their computer (this program will be used in an office setting, so the possibility of this happening on a particular day is nearly zero)).

Comment: It is possible to just monitor user input activity. Many programs do this, especially IM apps (although they're not .NET-based).

Comment: What if they're watching a movie and not touching anything? Does that qualify as active?

Comment: @Ian Jacobs, I would say no since you can loop a movie on your box, and be away from your computer, but you wouldn't be able to send any input via your mouse or keyboard if you were away from your computer.

Comment: What is the purpose of knowing if they are using the computer or not? What happens if they are not?

Comment: If I was being monitored like this, I'd write a program that sends keyboard messages every x seconds.  Actually, I did just that, to defeat the automatic screen saver at work.

Comment: @Gilbert, I will assume no one will be writing programs like this.  If anyone on our team did, it would increase operational risk, which would make people mad.

Comment: @Gilbert If I was being monitored like this, I'd find a new job!

Comment: I just had a talk about this with my boss, and he told me that these methods are a bit invasive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up [global hooks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804) for the [mouse](http://blog.bee-eee.com/2008/01/04/c-capture-the-mouse-get-a-global-hook-on-the-mouse/) and [keyboard](http://keymapper.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/keymapper/Classes/KeySniffer.cs) - WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL - which will allow you to monitor user activity - as long as your user is not, say, watching a film and not touching mouse or keyboard..

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd think about doing it would be to write an application that sits in the background and listens for mouse and keyboard messages using the `user32.dll` and assumes that the user is no longer using the computer if it doesn't hear any after a certain amount of time. Even then they might be watching a dvd or something though

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ugolog.com/pages/webcam-motion-detection-for-flash-flex-and-csharp

Webcam motion detection + mouse/keyboard hooks = Super Big Brother app.

Comment: Woah... Webcam motion detection? Unfortunately, I don't have webcams available :S +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a check using whether screen saver is running or not.

More info : http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/261540-detecting-screensaver-state

Answer (score 0):

best way to create some sort of Logging so that it sends usage logs to you. that way you can also analyze what features of the apps have been used actively. Capturing mouse moves and hooks might not make anvivirus on that box happy :)